UIViewにタッチ検知機能を付けたいが、正常に動作しない
Theosを使ってiOSのTweakを作ろうと思っています。
Objective-CやLogosを触ったことが無い為、手始めに、
既存のアプリケーションをHookし、画面上にUIViewを置き、そのUIViewをタップするとアラートが呼び出される。
という物を作ろうとしています。
最初はtouchesBeganが悪いのかと思い、UITapGestureRecognizerを使う方法も試してみましたが、自分の使い方が悪いのか、UIViewをタップするとクラッシュするようになってしまいました。
何か方法やコードの悪い点を指摘してくれる方が居れば幸いです。
以下が上手く動作しなかったコードです。
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestAlert : NSObject 

- (void)alert;

@end

@interface TouchTest : NSObject 

- (void)viewload;

@end

@implementation TestAlert

- (void)alert{

    UIViewController *view = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

        while (view.presentedViewController != nil && 
    !view.presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed) {
            view = view.presentedViewController;
        }

    UIAlertController *alertcontoller = 
    [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Touched"
                                        message:@"Touched"
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alertcontoller addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" 
                                                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault 
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {  
                                                  
      //ボタン動作内容

    }]];

    [view presentViewController:alertcontoller animated:YES completion:nil]; 

}
@end

@implementation TouchTest

- (void)viewload{
    mainWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

    UIView *menuicon = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    menuicon.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    menuicon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    menuicon.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [mainWindow addSubview:menuicon];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
    id showalert = [TestAlert alloc];
    [showalert alert];
}

@end

%hook IOSViewController

-(void)viewDidAppear:(bool)argument {
    id Callicon = [TouchTest alloc];
    [Callicon viewload];
    %orig;
}

%end


TouchTest で　viewを作っても　touchesBeganのオーバライドができていないので TouchTest内のtouchesBeganが実行されてないと考えます。
TestAlert を　UIVew　のサブクラスにして、touchesBeganのオーバーライドをしてIOSViewController　で　TestAlert を　作成すれば、TestAlertクラスに記述されている　touchesBegan　が実行されるでしょう。
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestAlert : NSObject

- (void)alert;

@end

@interface TouchTest  : UIView

@end

@implementation TestAlert

- (void)alert{

    UIViewController *view = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

        while (view.presentedViewController != nil && 
    !view.presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed) {
            view = view.presentedViewController;
        }

    UIAlertController *alertcontoller = 
    [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Touched"
                                        message:@"Touched"
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alertcontoller addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" 
                                                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault 
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {  
                                                  
      //ボタン動作内容

    }]];

    [view presentViewController:alertcontoller animated:YES completion:nil]; 

}
@end

@implementation TouchTest

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
    id showalert = [TestAlert alloc];
    [showalert alert];
}

@end

%hook IOSViewController

-(void)viewDidAppear:(bool)argument {

    UIWindow *mainWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    TouchTest *menuicon = [[TouchTest alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    menuicon.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    menuicon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    menuicon.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [mainWindow addSubview:menuicon];

    %orig;
}

%end


